# What is a good library for JSON serialization for Scala 2.8.1 for use in Eclipse

Tags: json, git, serialization, scala-2.8, eclipse-3.5

I have looked at https://github.com/debasishg/sjson and using EGit I was not able to import this code for Scala 2.8.1.

Ideally, this seems to be the best library that should work, but when I loaded master it is currently empty.

I am trying to use Jersey (http://jersey.java.net) to build a REST service in Scala, but the JSON serialization is where I am stuck, as I would prefer to use something written in Scala.

Unfortunately there isn't anything for Scala at http://json.org/.

So, how do I import SJSON for use in Scala 2.8.1, for Eclipse, or, is there a more updated library that would work as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [fork graph of that repo](https://github.com/debasishg/sjson/network), you will see [ginkel's version of sjson](https://github.com/ginkel/sjson) with:

- a non-empty master branch (note: debasishg's master branch isn't empty as well)
- [2.8.1. settings for the sbt build parameters](https://github.com/ginkel/sjson/commit/ba6dc348a6c07f7d723740997a0d68c7803b7181).

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was empty because I looked in the wrong directory, but I think the other fork may be a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Lift JSON has prebuilt 2.8.1 compatible versions at:

http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/net/liftweb/lift-json_2.8.1/

Please see "Installation" from:

https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json

Answer (score 2):

Writing REST services with Jersey (in Java) is what I do every day at work. I use the integration Jersey has with Jackson for JSON serialization and deserialization. Using another library with Jersey would be swimming upstream. You're using a REST library written in Java, so why not a JSON library in Java too, especially since it just works out of the box?

When I want to write a Scala REST service, I use SBT, the Scalatra web framework and lift-json. It works great.

I don't use Eclipse, but the selection of JSON library is orthogonal to what IDE/editor/etc you use. I would certainly never want to choose a library based on its ability to play nice in Eclipse.

If you're interested in using Scala to write a REST service (very quickly), start with this tutorial: http://blog.everythings-beta.com/?p=430

Add some case classes and lift-json support for parsing them. Excellent examples here: https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/ (scroll down) You can add lift-json to your SBT project with:

```
val lift_json = "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.1"
```

I've found lift-json excellent for both parsing and generating JSON. But if I'm using Jersey, I use the built in support for Jackson, since it is excellent and there's no reason to use anything else.

Comment: My only problem with using lift is that it is much larger than what I need, as this will only be a REST service, I am not going to be serving any pages, doing anything dynamic, just reacting to calls.

Comment: Yep - I agree 100%. Lift is great for what it does when you need it. That's why is suggest Scalatra - it's incredibly lightweight. Makes Jersey look like Lift. And you can use lift-json (the library) independent of Lift the framework using the dependency I posted. It's a pretty brilliant lightweight REST-service-in-5-minutes kind of setup.

EDIT - definitely check this out: http://blog.everythings-beta.com/?p=430 - Scalatra/SBT/MongoDB is my goto quick REST service platform now.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I will check them out now.  This is my first time trying to use REST with Scala, in case you didn't notice. :)